# JS dynamic variables or other solution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm building this web application-ordering system and i'm currently working on the cart part of the front end.

I have an Array that contains plain `1,2,3...` to count the products of my cart.
Every time the user clicks a product it simply checks the array and gives a certain id (for later php use) to the product on the cart.

Each product has each own attributes. I have no issue adding attributes to the product.
Each attribute gets also an id resulting in a `attribute_1_1,attribute_1_2` where the first number is the product No on the cart and the second one is the attribute No on the product.

Problem i'm facing is when removing an attribute.

If for example product 1 has `attribute_1_1,attribute_1_2,attribute_1_3` and i remove the No 2 attribute the JS will give the next added attribute the id of `attribute_1_4` therefor when checking in `php` how many are set it'll stop at 1 because `attribute_1_2` will be missing.

Either i have to make an array for each product for it's attributes (in which case i'll need dynamic variable `var ArraysAttr+SOMETHINGHERE=new Array();` which i don't know for now, or if there is another solution i'm missing please go ahead.

Thank you

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this. Why not just have an array of arrays for the attributes? Something like `[['attr1', 'attr2'], ['attr1', 'attr3']]`; Then you can determine which product has what attributes by the index of the array. Ie. product 1 has attr 1 and 2, product 2 has attr 1 and 3.

Comment: Yes but can i later on pass the array through an input to PHP or will i have to use AJAX?

Comment: I think i have it figured it out now, thank you